# facebook app not accessible from other user accounts

Tags: android, facebook, oauth, access-token

i have developed succesfully an android facebook app which creates events on facebook. i run it as an administrator runs smootly, everything ok. the problem is when i tried to run the application as a different user (i run it from a dummy account that i created) . While i could get information such as user name and user id and could succesfully create an event, when i run an fql request (or either graph api) such as

Select eid, name, start_time, end_time, location, creator, description, host, pic, attending_count, update_time, venue from event where eid IN (select eid from event_member where uid = me())

returns nothing. I added this account as administrator on facebook app settings the same problem. Then i tried something else, On graph explorer i tried to run the fql query as user. It returns the events that user attends. When i try to run the same query on behalf of the app it returns the response data :[]. (the same as the android implementation). I suspect that the dummy account could be the problem (it has only two friends) but i have added it as administrator. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

A lot could be at play here. From what I can see, you are asking for more than basic (public) info.

- **Has the user authorized the application to query the info you desire ?**

  Do you make sure that the user is authenticated with Facebook AND with your app before you   start asking for info ?

  A good start would be to test your queries plainly in a browser, see if you haven't made a mistake somewhere. You can add an accessToken parameter to your query to simulate that the user is well authenticated with your app. There is a tool to get fresh Access Tokens for each and everyone of your apps ([Access Token Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/)) -­>Make sure you are logged in with the right account.
- **Is the event allowing you to query information ?**

  Your case seems to make mention of Facebook events and attendees...
  Do you have sufficient rights to query info from the event.
- **Maybe your account has been caught by Facebook**

  Facebook offers alternatives for dummy accounts and does not encourage that practice at all.

  You can use test-users (See in Roles panel), or you could make some conditions inside your app... you find out what works best for you.

  As a mean to slow down this practice, Facebook sweeps for potential Dummy accounts and performs various "cuts". These "cuts" vary from closing of a channel to closing of said account. Same goes for any Open Graph Element (Events, Apps, etc) that do not comply with the Terms of Uses of Facebook.

All in all, these are all assumptions and hypothesis... I would like to help you more... but you're not giving us a lot to work with here.

Can you please update your question with more concrete scenarios (and better formatting)

Comment: First of all thanks for your quick reply. As I mentioned i tested the queries with graph api explorer tool and here it is : if i choose as the application the graph api explorer the queries return indeed the events that the dummy user created or attends. Although if i choose as the application the app it does not return anything. You might be right about Facebook policy and dummy account . But it strikes me odd that i can create from my app an event (which is potentially more harmful)

Comment: I foud the solution. You were partialy i had not declared the right permissions. (user_events)